# padding is not disappearing in html

Tags: html, css, padding

[image]

This example is based on the w3schools.

I  want to attach the "nav" part to the header. The red notification part is issue. I don't know why the "nav" is not attached to header. I applied the padding as 0 px. Who knows how to solve the problem? or am I misunderstanding  padding? Thank you for the answer.

My html source is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

header, footer {
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    float: left;
    max-width: 160px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0em;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    padding : 25px;
    border : 1px solid gray;
    background-color:orange;
}

nav ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

article {
    margin-left: 170px;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>City Gallery</h1>
  </header>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <article>
    <h1>London</h1>
    <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
    <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has beeon a major settlement for two millennia, it's history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
  </article>

  <footer>Copyright ? W3Schools.com</footer>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does `header` have any default margin set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your nav is built using `ul` tag, which has `margin` property set by default

this should solve your problem:

```
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

also, keep in mind that 0 shouldn't be used with units (it's a good practice)

Comment: Thanks for great answer. I clearly understand what I wrong.

Comment: using developer tools in your browser is really helpful in such situations

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `margin:0;` will also get rid of the space from the footer.
To only remove the space from your header 
Set   `margin-top:0;` in  nav ul.

Answer (score -1):

Reset ul margin.

```
nav ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: This answer is exactly the same as the one before, and doesn't bring anything more useful than the one before.

Comment: You have right, but I have not seen when I typing my answer.